# Workaround for saving / editing a VSTS test case

Tags: azure-devops, manual-testing

I have an issue with VSTS manual test cases. When I try to edit one, I got an error message as follows:

> An element with the same key already exists in the dictionary
>
> e</n.prototype.add@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-area-1319062352-vWRYJ179SKTshLwEQt_Tl9g==:3:2142
>   ki</n.prototype.onAddParameterInSteps@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-view-1316919717-vxhr2NM2m2AZNsRLuD0JDHQ==:36:46195
>   bi</n.prototype.onAddParameterInSteps@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-view-1316919717-vxhr2NM2m2AZNsRLuD0JDHQ==:36:40049
>   tf</t.prototype.onAddParameterInSteps@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-view-1316919717-vxhr2NM2m2AZNsRLuD0JDHQ==:36:62452
>   bi</n.prototype._updateParametersRefCountOnAddingStep/<@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-view-1316919717-vxhr2NM2m2AZNsRLuD0JDHQ==:36:39659
>   .each@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-1370396394-vpQOf5w8kp8_6mpJi9ABtBQ==:15:12291
>   bi</n.prototype._updateParametersRefCountOnAddingStep@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-view-1316919717-vxhr2NM2m2AZNsRLuD0JDHQ==:36:39614
>   bi</n.prototype._calculateParameterRefCountsFromSteps@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-view-1316919717-vxhr2NM2m2AZNsRLuD0JDHQ==:36:40691
>   bi</n.prototype.setParameters@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-view-1316919717-vxhr2NM2m2AZNsRLuD0JDHQ==:36:35794
>   yt</t.prototype.readParameters@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-async135478241-v-UPjjKxU6f1kHHOWlhqz1Q==:14:58274
>   yt</t.prototype._onStepsLoaded@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-async135478241-v-UPjjKxU6f1kHHOWlhqz1Q==:14:72430
>   o/<@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-common-1174969321-vP7TYoPIwwgcmodAk6tzLZw==:53:215
>   u@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-async135478241-v-UPjjKxU6f1kHHOWlhqz1Q==:14:81038
>   yt</t.prototype._fetch@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-async135478241-v-UPjjKxU6f1kHHOWlhqz1Q==:14:81408
>   yt</t.prototype.invalidate@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-async135478241-v-UPjjKxU6f1kHHOWlhqz1Q==:14:57579
>   c</n.prototype._onFieldChanged@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-async636480634-vHvWOSM8E8rCxBa3bYo2R7w==:149:2040
>   o/<@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-common-1174969321-vP7TYoPIwwgcmodAk6tzLZw==:53:215
>   u@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-common-1174969321-vP7TYoPIwwgcmodAk6tzLZw==:94:177
>   o</n.prototype.invokeHandlers@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-common-1174969321-vP7TYoPIwwgcmodAk6tzLZw==:94:526
>   tr</n.prototype.fireEvent@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-area-1319062352-vWRYJ179SKTshLwEQt_Tl9g==:35:100720
>   tr</n.prototype.fireFieldChange@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-area-1319062352-vWRYJ179SKTshLwEQt_Tl9g==:35:103810
>   tr</n.prototype.evaluateFields@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-area-1319062352-vWRYJ179SKTshLwEQt_Tl9g==:35:112953
>   tr</n.prototype.evaluate@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-area-1319062352-vWRYJ179SKTshLwEQt_Tl9g==:35:112662
>   tr</n.prototype._takeUpdateResult@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-area-1319062352-vWRYJ179SKTshLwEQt_Tl9g==:35:110218
>   vi</t.prototype._beginSaveWorkItemsInternal/</</<@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-area-1319062352-vWRYJ179SKTshLwEQt_Tl9g==:35:74066
>   vi</t.prototype.beginGetWorkItemTypeExtensions@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-area-1319062352-vWRYJ179SKTshLwEQt_Tl9g==:35:69585
>   vi</t.prototype._beginSaveWorkItemsInternal/</<@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-area-1319062352-vWRYJ179SKTshLwEQt_Tl9g==:35:74001
>   .each@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-1370396394-vpQOf5w8kp8_6mpJi9ABtBQ==:15:12291
>   vi</t.prototype._beginSaveWorkItemsInternal/<@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-area-1319062352-vWRYJ179SKTshLwEQt_Tl9g==:35:73876
>   rt@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-common-1174969321-vP7TYoPIwwgcmodAk6tzLZw==:59:938
>   l/<@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-common-1174969321-vP7TYoPIwwgcmodAk6tzLZw==:59:1252
>   i.Callbacks/l@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-1370396394-vpQOf5w8kp8_6mpJi9ABtBQ==:15:35816
>   i.Callbacks/s.fireWith@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-1370396394-vpQOf5w8kp8_6mpJi9ABtBQ==:15:36641
>   w@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-1370396394-vpQOf5w8kp8_6mpJi9ABtBQ==:15:73448
>   .send/t/<@https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-1370396394-vpQOf5w8kp8_6mpJi9ABtBQ==:15:79367
>
> Session Id: 73288d72-580f-42fb-9aeb-f5cadb6b3bc5

I only have this issue if a test step contains parameters. After refreshing the page and reopening the test case, the color code is black and it doesn't display the Save button. Also, the dropdown of the `...` is empty.

Existing tests are fine, running them is also possible. Working with bugs, user stories and tasks is fine.

Screenshots can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4M9w.jpg)

Is there a way to workaround this?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT of the black header or the error or both?

Comment: Both, I just tried to update a test case contains parameters, but didn't see any issue.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT sure, give me a minute

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT added screenshots

Comment: Still cannot reproduce the issue, have you tried clean the browser cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the parameter name "@length", remove it or rename it to others like "@length1" would works.

This seems to be a bug with VSTS, I have help you created a feedback on MS Connect Page, refer to this link for details: ["An element with the same key already exists in the dictionary" error occurs when save a test case contains a parameter named as "length".](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2980527/an-element-with-the-same-key-already-exists-in-the-dictionary-error-occurs-when-save-a-test-case-contains-a-parameter-named-as-length)

Comment: Ah, right. Do you know if there's a reference with reserved keywords?